# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im new to coding so im recieving a javascript error on the last line can anyone help me with this? The file has been minified. Much Appreciated

```
;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    String.prototype.filename = function(extension) {
        var s = this.replace(/\\/g, '/');
        s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        return extension ? s.replace(/[?#].+$/, '') : s.split('.')[0];
    }
    jQuery("img").each(function() {
        var alt = jQuery(this).attr('alt');
        if (alt === "") {
            var namefile = jQuery(this).attr('src').filename();
            var rep = namefile.replace(/[_#?%*$@!=&]/g, '-');
            var temp = rep.split('-');
            var alt = '';
            for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                alt = alt + ' ' + temp[i];
            }
            jQuery(this).attr('alt', alt);
        }
        if (alt === undefined) {
            var namefile = jQuery(this).attr('src').filename();
            var rep = namefile.replace(/[_#?%*$@!=]/g, '-');
            var temp = rep.split('-');
            var alt = '';
            for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                alt = alt + ' ' + temp[i];
            }
            jQuery(this).attr('alt', alt);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the error? And how have you debugged the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code unminified:

```
;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    String.prototype.filename = function(extension) {
        var s = this.replace(/\\/g, '/');
        s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        return extension ? s.replace(/[?#].+$/, '') : s.split('.')[0];
    }
    jQuery("img").each(function() {
        var alt = jQuery(this).attr('alt');
        if (alt === "") {
            var namefile = jQuery(this).attr('src').filename();
            var rep = namefile.replace(/[_#?%*$@!=&]/g, '-');
            var temp = rep.split('-');
            var alt = '';
            for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                alt = alt + ' ' + temp[i];
            }
            jQuery(this).attr('alt', alt);
        }
        if (alt === undefined) {
            var namefile = jQuery(this).attr('src').filename();
            var rep = namefile.replace(/[_#?%*$@!=]/g, '-');
            var temp = rep.split('-');
            var alt = '';
            for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                alt = alt + ' ' + temp[i];
            }
            jQuery(this).attr('alt', alt);
        }
    });
});
```

You can see that there is a missing `;` on the 7th line, after the closing brace.

Here is the fixed unminified code;

```
;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    String.prototype.filename = function(extension) {
        var s = this.replace(/\\/g, '/');
        s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        return extension ? s.replace(/[?#].+$/, '') : s.split('.')[0];
    };
    jQuery("img").each(function() {
        var alt = jQuery(this).attr('alt');
        if (alt === "") {
            var namefile = jQuery(this).attr('src').filename();
            var rep = namefile.replace(/[_#?%*$@!=&]/g, '-');
            var temp = rep.split('-');
            var alt = '';
            for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                alt = alt + ' ' + temp[i];
            }
            jQuery(this).attr('alt', alt);
        }
        if (alt === undefined) {
            var namefile = jQuery(this).attr('src').filename();
            var rep = namefile.replace(/[_#?%*$@!=]/g, '-');
            var temp = rep.split('-');
            var alt = '';
            for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                alt = alt + ' ' + temp[i];
            }
            jQuery(this).attr('alt', alt);
        }
    });
});
```

And the fixed minified code;

```
;jQuery( document ).ready(function() { String.prototype.filename=function(extension){ var s= this.replace(/\\/g, '/'); s= s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/')+ 1); return extension? s.replace(/[?#].+$/, ''): s.split('.')[0]; }; jQuery("img").each(function () { var alt = jQuery(this).attr('alt'); if(alt === ""){ var namefile = jQuery(this).attr('src').filename(); var rep = namefile.replace(/[_#?%*$@!=&]/g,'-'); var temp = rep.split('-'); var alt =''; for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) { alt = alt+' '+temp[i]; } jQuery(this).attr('alt',alt); } if(alt === undefined){ var namefile = jQuery(this).attr('src').filename(); var rep = namefile.replace(/[_#?%*$@!=]/g,'-'); var temp = rep.split('-'); var alt =''; for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) { alt = alt+' '+temp[i]; } jQuery(this).attr('alt',alt); } }); });
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the backslash in the regex.

```
this.replace(/\/g, '/'); // wrong
```

```
this.replace(/\\/g, '/'); // right
```

Comment: The backslash was escaped in their original post (see [original source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b62a1d99-dba5-4a23-af5e-dcc93fa06716/view-source)). @guest271314's edit has removed that.

Comment: @JackWilsdon: How did you know to look at the source? The original question doesn't show the escaping when rendered on the page. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46384077/1 Only the source view reveals that.

Comment: I was editing the post to put the code into a code block and just copied from there when I originally looked at the question, I only noticed it was missing in the rendered version when copying it again to format it for my answer.

Comment: They should revert it back to the original. With the line breaks, the missing semicolon no longer is an issue.

Comment: I submitted an edit for the post yesterday to re-minify the code, but it looks like it was rejected.